# Dual debugger Java + (Perl/Python) script

Tags: java, python, perl, debugging

This question just came up in a discussion and i am curious to know .

Is it possible to have a debugger that can debug 2 languages . For example . If i have  Java program that references/opens/accesses/ a script (Perl or Python) then is it possible to have a debugger to be able to debug the Perl/Python script ?

Note : Logging is not an acceptable debugging technique here .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, alter the host program (the java program ) so that it runs the perl program in a debugger

You might well run into problems with the way that debuggers "attach" in different programming language environments.  `perl -d` assumes a tty is there for interactive commands whereas java does something completely different